# Newsstand App Content

Tags: objective-c, ios, newsstand-kit

I have done a fair amount of searching, and have decided that I must be an idiot.

I am currently building out a Newsstand app which will pull PDFs from a server, however, having subscribed to a Newsstand app, I know for a fact that these magazines are for more complex than a PDF. My question is, how the hell are these custom magazines (with videos and pannable pictures) actually built, and what would I have to do to be able to pull them from a server?

I don't even know what file type these custom magazines are, and from everything that I've read, it seems to be assumed that I would just know.

Please help me out, I am utterly confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newsstand apis aren't concerned about the format of your magazine or newspaper.  Newsstand simply manages the 'NKAssetDownloads' and subscriptions.  Apple recommend that any assets you have should be bundled up into one single piece of downloadable content, although the newsstand api does allow you to download multiple assets if you wish (really complicates things though, so I recommend you don't do that!) http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/NKAssetDownload_Class/NKAssetDownload/NKAssetDownload.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NKAssetDownload

Instead what you should do is package all of your magazine pages, videos, images etc into one zip file, which you download as an NKAssetDownload.  Once this completes you can unzip it (you can allow newsstand do decide where to stick it all) and then do whatever you like with it in your app.  If you have images you can display them in image views, html pages can be displayed in webviews etc.  It depends what format your magazine is in.

How the actual magazine is made before it reaches your app is a different matter.  For the app I work on the newspaper company provides us with a bunch of pdf pages which we then display in the app with some custom drawing and effects.  They also provide us with some plain text pages and coordinate information so we can do other funky stuff.

Comment: I knew about the NKAssetDownloads, but I didn't know how I would present the actual assets. Do you usually load the assets with tags and then use thos tags to load into a pre made .xib or what? I've never done this before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to decide what the format of the magazine is yourself.  You should know what the structure is etc because you create that package yourself, put it on the server it will be hosted, and then download it with newsstand.  If the only thing in your package is say an image of page 1 of the magazine, and it's called "1.png" then you know that exists, and you would show 1.png in an image view.  You could also create a definition of your magazine in the package (some kind of xml file perhaps) that outlines the structure of the magazine to give you more flexibility with the issue structure.